# how to add a zero in month number (padding) in datetime pandas

Tags: datetime, pandas, padding

I have a column as datetime in a pandas data frame. with this function:

```
data['yearMonth'] = data.ts_placed.map(lambda x: '{year}-{month}'.format(year=x.year,month=x.month))
```

I convert the datetime object from

```
2012-08-06 10:25:39
```

to

```
2012-8
```

what i need is to get the object as

```
2012-08
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
data['yearMonth'] = data.ts_placed.map(lambda x: '{year}-{month:02}'.format(year=x.year,month=x.month))
```

or, if `x` is a pandas Timestamp or `datetime.datetime`, use `strftime`:

```
data['yearMonth'] = data.ts_placed.map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))
```

Comment: awesome! check the syntax there is an '  between the last two brackets in the second line of code

Comment: I think in the second example it is possible simplify it to `data.ts_placed.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')` , but that may have been added in a recent version.